# ActiveRecord as_json return different column names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to return a JSON representation of an ActiveRecord but instead of having the JSON string contain the model's column names for the Keys I would like to have it display something different per column. Is there a way to do this? here is my example line

```
record.as_json(root: false, :only => [:message, :user])
```

I basically want it to return the message and the user columns, but I want to call them something else when it gets them.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're overcomplicating this. You only want two columns so why not just do it by hand?

```
def some_controller
  #...
  json = {
    new_name_for_message: r.message,
    new_name_for_user:    r.user
  }
  render json: json, status: :ok
end
```

Build a two element Hash and hand it off to the JSON rendering system.

Answer (score 1):

```
record.as_json(root: false, :only => [:user], :methods => [:message_html])
```

and define that method on record.